# Understanding what why the pointer keeps being reassigned here

Tags: c++

I have run into a problem where my pointer keeps being incorrectly reassigned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Simplex {
    std::vector<double> &pmatrix;
    double pi;
    double *ph;

    public:
        double pstar;
        Simplex(std::vector<double> &otherpmatrix)
            :
            pmatrix(otherpmatrix)
            {
            }

        void evaluate(){
            ph=&pmatrix[0];
            for (int i=0;i<pmatrix.size();i++){
                pi=pmatrix[i];
                if (pi>*ph){
                    ph=&pi;
                }
                std::cout<<" ph is now "<<*ph<<"\n";  
            }  
        }
};

int main()
{
    double p0=0;
    double p1=2;
    double p2=1;
    std::vector<double> pmatrix = {p0,p1,p2};

    Simplex simplex(pmatrix);
    simplex.evaluate();

    //std::cout<<"pmatrix[i][2] elements from pmatrix in main "<<pmatrix[0].y<<" "<<pmatrix[1].y<<" "<<pmatrix[2].y<<"\n"<<simplex.pstar.x0;

return 1;
}
```

My hope was that `ph` points to the highest of `p0`,`p1`,`p2` by the end of the for loop. That was the intent. Instead, it just keeps being assigned on every loop. This doesn't make sense since the code in the for loop block should only run if `pi>`*ph`, which is not always the case.

The output is:

```
 ph is now 0
 ph is now 2
 ph is now 1
```

The code in the for block is being executed each time, which doesn't make sense since in the case where `i`=2, `pi`=1 and `*ph`=2. So I would expect only 2 executions. 
Can someone explain the output?

Comment: the pointer `ph` points to the value assigned in `pi`. When you change `pi`, the value `ph` points to the current value stored in `pi`. No need to update the pointer itself. Basic pointer arithmetics

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
        ph=&pmatrix[0];
        for (int i=0;i<pmatrix.size();i++){
            pi=pmatrix[i];
            if (pi>*ph){
                ph=&pi;
            }
            std::cout<<" ph is now "<<*ph<<"\n";  
        }
```

`pi` is the member, it is a `double` and its adress is always the same no matter if you assign a different value to it. Hence `ph = &pi` will make `ph` point to that member. When you print `*ph` you will print the value of that member, which in each iteraton you set to the current element `pi=pmatrix[i];`.

It is not clear why you made `pi` a member when it only has meaning inside that method. Anyhow, storing the value in any `double` will not help you to retrieve a pointer to where that value came from.

If you want the pointer to point to the max element in `pmatrix` instead, then do that:

```
if (pi>*ph){
    ph=&pmatrix[i];
}
```

but I would rather suggest you to get rid of pointers altogether. There is no need to use them here (storing the index would achieve the same) and it can cause confusion.